# Robocopy corrupted files indication

Tags: powershell, robocopy, corruption

One simple theoretical question.
If I use robocopy command, for example to copy from laptop to an external hdd, does it has some mechanism to detect corrupted files that have been corrupted during the copying? 
If it does, will the "/r" help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robocopy does not have a verify switch though several similar applications do. XXCopy being a popular one.

You can use /r and /w to retry a certain number of times and wait a certain number of seconds between each retry which helps with network issues.

You could also do a compare with Get-FileHash after the copy is complete.

Here's a very simple example.

```
$source = 'C:\temp'
$destination = 'C:\temp2'
#copy files
robocopy $source $destination /z /e /r:1 /w:1
#get all files, hash them, select just the path and file hash
#group by the hash, and finally get the ones that only have 1 item
#anything successfully copied will have 2 hashes that match
Get-ChildItem $source,$destination | Get-FileHash | Select-Object Path, Hash | Group-Object Hash | Where-Object Count -eq 1
```

For a 25GB random sample of files I had on hand, the verification only took ~1 minute.

EDIT:
If you are on v3 you can use the following Get-FileHash, not that this is a quick function and has not been fully tested for all environments or edge cases.

```
function Get-TestFileHash
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline = $true,
                   Position=0)]
        [String]
        $FileName,
        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName]
        $Algorithm = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName]::SHA256
    )
    Process
    {
        Foreach($File in $FileName){
            $FilePath = Get-Item $File
            If($FilePath -is [System.IO.FileInfo]){
                $Stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($FilePath,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
                $StringBuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
                [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create($Algorithm).ComputeHash($Stream)|%{[Void]$StringBuilder.Append($_.ToString("x2"))}
                $stream.Close()
                $stream.Dispose()
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Algorithm=$Algorithm 
                    Hash=$StringBuilder.ToString().ToUpper()
                    Path=$FilePath
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample from this command:

```
PS > dir | Get-TestFileHash

Algorithm Hash                                                             Path                                               
--------- ----                                                             ----                                               
SHA256    CB0363573C31B7E4684A3D620C125DF0CC7C9335379A8C3D08710EA5B65EA014 C:\Users\Bob\documents\afile1.txt
SHA256    E2F6395909A0FF358A3A5ACBEC5B60A2212FE6511D3E593E0940BA0A51D1DD66 C:\Users\Bob\documents\afile2.txt
SHA256    88EB168DD68C484226E5B3E0626AF30B1364DA0D6B53EA168649AB472C5F9FB7 C:\Users\Bob\documents\afile3.txt
SHA256    52A20D3072E8AA919746176C222B355CE7E7E3FA704E81561E366A8934C37509 C:\Users\Bob\documents\afile4.txt
SHA256    DD61CEFC783E581F1A5D490E5A04CE6B7E892201221ABB0E651AD7C272B4B279 C:\Users\Bob\documents\afile5.txt
SHA256    954B7CC9846F800FA5BE5AD14EB8CA9FAA38FBE936E93DA9599B1026EEEF7C06 C:\Users\Bob\documents\afile6.txt
SHA256    0F63AC1AD9A0D51362667B108DFFAED26E283B547F1694DF7DFF8A74357AA68F C:\Users\Bob\documents\afile7.txt
```

Comment: This logic will actually help me a lot, but I don't have Get-FileHash command. I am using a powershell V3. Is this an built in function or I need to create it ?

Comment: Was added in v4 I believe. If you are on v3 you can use a custom function to perform a similar operation. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Just one question, If I have a lot of sub folders, I should go with a "Get-ChildItem $source,$destination -recurse | ...." am I on a right track? :)

Comment: Yes, you would need to recurse to check all of the sub directories.